# HTML5 Javascript Windows 8 store app camera

Tags: javascript, html, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Morning,

I have created an app using html5 and javascript for the store, as part of this app, the users can take photos using Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI() which is then sent to an API and subsequent database.

All is working fine and dandy on the Dell Lattitude ST2 running windows 8.
The users are going to be in some dark and stinky places, so the flash must fire off at least on automatic.

As this isn't a current OS, we are testing a few other tablets with the app running Windows 8.1 e.g. Lenovo Thinkpad. We have found that the flash doesn't fire at all using this, in fact the dialog that opens looks totally different from the camera app in the programs.

Does anyone know why this is and how to make the flash fire using the `Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI()` method, short of sending this through `PhoneGap` which we will consider if that's the only option.

Comment: I wonder if anyone actually builds apps in this way or use of phone gap is the only answer.